# High chart Categories work as Series Legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, series

I would like to display a legend for the x-axis categories; I would like it to look just like the series legend, and I would like it to work exactly in the same way, that you turn a category off in the chart by clicking on that same category on the legend.

**What I did is the following** 
I have charts where I can disable and enable categories of it using JQuery button and everything is working fine .For Now, I only disable and Enable the categories by button click.

What I want to do is to remove the categories when I click the button and not disable it only.In other words; I want the button to work as the series legend buttons in the Highchart where the chart will be redraw .

**Example** if I click **Feb** the category **Feb** will disappear and will have an **empty category** will be between Jan & March.And I don't Want that . I want the chart to redraw again without the category.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ('@Model.Data' == "") return;
    var Title = '@Model.Title';
    var X_Axis_Title = '@Model.X_Axis_Title';
    var Y_Axis_Title = '@Model.Y_Axis_Title';
    var ChartContainer = '@Model.ContainerName';
    var ChartCategories = [];
    var ChartCategoriesMaleData = [];
    var ChartCategoriesFemalData = [];
    var ChartCategoriesTotalMFData = [];
    var ChartData = [];
    var SeriesNames = [];
    var ChartDataStr = '@Model.Data';
    var SeriesNamesStr = '@Model.SeriesNames';
    //alert("ChartContainer=" + ChartContainer);

    function createDynamicCategories(chart, legendContainerId) {
        // Capturing data from chart options:
        var categories = chart.options.xAxis.categories;
        var series = chart.options.series;
        // Creating a button  for each category and place it in container:
        for (var i in chart.xAxis[0].categories) {
            checkboxHtml = '<label><button type ="submit" onclick="onclick" id="category_' + i + '">' + chart.xAxis[0].categories[i] + '</button></label>'
            $('#' + legendContainerId).append(checkboxHtml);
        }
        // Binding events to buttons:

        $('#' + legendContainerId + ' button[type ="submit"]').on('click', function () {
            var buttonID = this.id;
            alert(buttonID);
            alert(buttonID.indexOf('_'));
            var strs = [];
            var strs = buttonID.split('_');
            alert(strs[1]);
            var ID = strs[1];
            var hiddenSeries = [];
            var hiddenCategories = [];

            // Collecting disabled categories:
            hiddenSeries[ID] = null;
            hiddenCategories[ID] = ' ';

            // Updating series data:
            for (var s in chart.series){
                chart.series[s].setData($.extend([], series[s].data, hiddenSeries));
            }
            // Updating categories:
            chart.xAxis[0].setCategories($.extend([], categories, hiddenCategories));
            // Redrawing chart:
            chart.redraw();
        });
    }
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: ChartContainer,
            defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            style: {
                left: 'auto',
                right: '30px',
                top: '70px',
                bottom: 'auto'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                this.x + ': ' + this.y + ' mm';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [20, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6]
        }]
    });
    createDynamicCategories(chart, ChartContainer);
});
```

Comment: When I click on button, categories should disappear. Then what should happend?

Comment: See now when I click it disappear (I assign null value).So actually i made it empty . Example if I click Feb the category Feb will disappear will have an empty category will be between Jan & March.And i don't Want that . i want the chart to redraw again without the category.

Comment: Instead of nulls, you nee to remove serie and add new one or use setData.

Comment: if i remove it how can I get it back then on the second click.?

Comment: Well only what comes to my mind is use additiaonl varaible which will keep values of serie before remove, then after remove, when you need to recover, you use this variable.